# readdir on AWS EFS doesn't return all files in directory

Tags: c++, linux, amazon-web-services, readdir, amazon-efs

After having written many files to a series of folders on EFS (10k or so). Readdir stops returning all of the files in each directory.

I have a C++ application that in one part of its process it generates a lot of files and each file is given a symlink. After that I need to get a list of the file in a folder to then select a subset to rename. When I run the function that gets the list of files, it does not return all the files that are actually there. This code runs fine on my local machine, but on an AWS server with a mounted EFS drive, it stops working after a while.

In order to troubleshoot this issue, I have made my code only write one file at a time. I have also setup my code to use getFiles() to give me a count of how many files there are in a folder after writing each batch of files (around 17 files). When the number of files reaches ~950 files, getFiles() starts listing ~910 files and no longer increments. When its writing files, the files are varied but fairly small (2 bytes - 300K) and its writing about 200 files a second. Each file also has a symlink created to it.

When reading and writing files I am using posix open(), write(), read() and close(). I have verified that I do in fact close all files after reading or writing.

I am trying to figure out:
1. Why is readdir not working? Or why is it not listing all the files?
2. What is different about EFS that could be causing issues?

These are the functions I am using to get the list of files in a folder:

```
DIR * FileUtil::getDirStream(std::string path) {

bool success = false;

if (!folderExists(path)){
    return NULL;
}

DIR * dir = opendir(path.c_str());
success = dir != NULL;

int count = 0;
while(!success){

    int fileRetryDelay = BlazingConfig::getInstance()->getFileRetryDelay();
    const int sleep_milliseconds = (count+1)*fileRetryDelay;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep_milliseconds));

    std::cout<<"Was unable to get Dir stream for "<<path<<std::endl;
    dir = opendir(path.c_str());
    success = dir != NULL;

    count++;
    if(count > 6){
        break;
    }
}

if(success == -1){
    std::cout<<"Can't get Dir stream for "<<path<<". Error was: "<<errno<<std::endl;
}
return dir;
}

int FileUtil::getDirEntry(DIR * dirp, struct dirent * & prevDirEntry, struct dirent * & dirEntry){

bool success = false;

if (dirp == NULL){
    return -1;
}

int returnCode = readdir_r(dirp, prevDirEntry, &dirEntry);
success = (dirEntry == NULL && returnCode == 0) || dirEntry != NULL;

int count = 0;
while(!success){

    int fileRetryDelay = BlazingConfig::getInstance()->getFileRetryDelay();
    const int sleep_milliseconds = (count+1)*fileRetryDelay;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep_milliseconds));

    std::cout<<"Was unable to get dirent with readdir"<<std::endl;

    returnCode = readdir_r(dirp, prevDirEntry, &dirEntry);
    success = (dirEntry == NULL && returnCode == 0) || dirEntry != NULL;

    count++;
    if(count > 6){
        break;
    }
}

if(success == -1){
    std::cout<<"Can't get dirent with readdir. Error was: "<<errno<<std::endl;
}
return returnCode;
}

std::vector<std::string> FileUtil::getFiles(std::string baseFolder){
DIR *dir = getDirStream(baseFolder);
std::vector <std::string> subFolders;
if (dir != NULL) {
    struct dirent *prevDirEntry = NULL;
    struct dirent *dirEntry = NULL;
    int len_entry = offsetof(struct dirent, d_name) + fpathconf(dirfd(dir), _PC_NAME_MAX) + 1;
    prevDirEntry = (struct dirent *)malloc(len_entry);

    int returnCode = getDirEntry(dir, prevDirEntry, dirEntry);

    while (dirEntry != NULL) {
        if( dirEntry->d_type == DT_REG || dirEntry->d_type == DT_LNK){
            std::string name(dirEntry->d_name);
            subFolders.push_back(name);
        }
        returnCode = getDirEntry(dir, prevDirEntry, dirEntry);
    }

    free(prevDirEntry);
    closedir (dir);
} else {
    std::cout<<"Could not open directory err num is"<<errno<<std::endl;
    /* could not open directory */
    perror ("");

}

return subFolders;
}
```

The functions were written this way to try to be as robust as possible, since there can be many threads performing file operations, I wanted to be able to have the code retry in case of any failures. Unfortunately when getFiles() returns the wrong result, it does not give me any indication of failure.

Note: when I use readdir as opposed to readdir_r I still have the same issue.

Comment: Fyi, `success == -1` as a conditional will *always* be false.